# How to dynamically exclude the object from the chaininig in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, chaining

I've got the object structure, where `utils` and `utils.not` takes the same prototype (with `exist` method). I simplified it for make it more clear:

```
var negative = true;
if(negative){
  //when negative===true, I want to run exist() through not object
  tests.utils.not.exist();
} else {
  tests.utils.exist();
}
```

Is there any other way to exclude `not` from the chain instead of using `IF`? If I wanted to change `not` object into another, eg `positive`, I could do this simply like that:

```
tests.utils[negative ? 'not':'positive'].exist();
```

But how can I dynamically exclude `not` object from the chain?
My `IF` syntax works fine, but I just wonder if there is another (more elegant) way in JS.

Comment: Is this Chai? If so, please ask a question about Chai.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Proxies to set default behaviour and then call them the way you want take a look at the example

```js
var handler = {
  get: function(target, name) {
    return target.hasOwnProperty(name) ? target[name] : target["default"];
  }
};

var p = new Proxy({
 default : {
  exists : function(){
   return 1;
  }
 },
 not : {
  exists : function(){
   return 2;
  }
 }       
}, handler);

let negative = false;

let x = p[negative === true ? "not" : "default"];
console.log(x.exists());
```

Take a look at [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: Proxies are never necessary, here included. You could remove the proxy entirely and it wouldn’t make a difference.

Comment: I just intended to say that we can add default return types to objects, for say by default return exists() instead of not.exists()

Comment: Proxies aren’t necessary to do that either. Using one is misleading.

Comment: So the answer would be the same thing without proxies ? Just add default behaviour to the object

Comment: Yep``````.``````

Answer (score 1):

The only way to remove the condition (if or ternary operator) is hiding it within the `exist()` method:

```
tests.utils.exist(negative); // true or false
```

And let the exist method choose the logic. But I think your current code is clearer and the explicit `if` helps to read and understand it better, I don't see it as a non-elegant code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is useful, but you can do this.

```
var objectToTrigger = negative ? tests.utils.not : tests.utils;
objectToTrigger.exist();
```

Comment: yep, finally I did sth similar to this within the function and just return the chain with or without not object `objectToTrigger(negative).exist()`

Answer (score 0):

Since your 'to be executed' method depends upon the condition (negative === true), you can't really avoid the check. However, you can write some smart code:

```
let method = test.utils.exist; 
if (negative) {
  method = test.utils.not.exist;
}

method();
```